# Is it possible to automatically input all .tex files from a subfolder into a document in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

I am working on a large document in Overleaf, and in order to keep an overview over the chapters, I have arranged them in a subfolder with a naming structure like this:

000_title.tex

001_abstract.tex

01_introduction.tex

02_theoretical_background.tex

I am subsequently adding more chapters to this, and sometimes changing their order. Hence I was wondering if it's possible to automatically include all files in that subfolder in sorting order into the document? I have seen that it is possible in LaTeX only through bash scripts, so I figured this wouldn't work in Overleaf.

Or maybe I'm not seeing things clearly and there is an even better solution to this problem?

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be directed to Overleaf's helpdesk. I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: In that case sorry for spamming this forum, I'll direct myself to their support then!

Comment: Your document will not be _very_ large presumably, maybe 20 chapters max? In such a case it would probably take you less time to just adjust one or two `\include` statements if something changes, instead of trying to create a fully automatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use those scripts, overleaf runs with shell-escape on linux texlive 2020 so for example

```
 \input{|ls}
```

will list the filenames in the current folder.

Comment: I'm from the Overleaf Support team and I confirm that you can run basic shell scripts. However, I wouldn't recommend this: It adds another layers of code and makes things much more difficult to debug, with (IMHO) a negligible gain.

Comment: @yo' yes I wouldn't disagree with that (which is one reason I only showed `ls` and left the processing as an exercise for the reader) also marijn's comment under the question.